# How To Refresh Listview From Adapter or Another Activity in Android?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

hello I need to refresh my List view From Adapter class or another activity.Please reply as soon as possible.

Comment: Actually what you want to do ? adapter.notifydatasetchanged() this will refresh the content of listview now let me know what you want do

Comment: Need a lot more context than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by just creating a static reference of your activity where you puted listview and calling the referesh function, after that just call that function in Adapter or any other class by just taking reference of that static variable of that class.
For eg: Classname.stataticvar.fucntion

Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
//declare a static variable
public static MyListAdapter adapter;

//at the place where you call the adapter constructor;
MyListAdapter adapter=new MyListAdapter(//parameters here);
MyListAdapter=adapter;

//call from anywhere
try{
  ClassName.adapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
}catch(Throwable e){
  //error occured. Probably null
}
```

Comment: oh and next what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your `Adapter` whenever the corresponding set of data is modified.